# Losing Reference to Assigned View

Tags: android, view, reference, dialog, android-preferences

So I am extending the ListPreference in order to achieve the effect I need.

I would like to have a titleView, a messageView, and then the listView in my dialog.

I override the onCreateDialogView() method in order to do this and am able to display the messageView successfully by creating a textview and adding it to the view with this code:

```
@Override
protected View onCreateDialogView() {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    ListView lv = (ListView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_layout, null);

    _messageView= (TextView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_header, null);
    _messageView.setText("Hello World");
    lv.addHeaderView(_messageView);

    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(getContext(), R.layout.dialog_list_choice, getEntries());
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    return lv;
}
```

Now when I assign the created TextView the variable _messageView and set the text it works fine.
However, when I click the preference, I want the dialog's messageView text to change.
I do so with the following code:

```
public void showWithCode(String code){
    if (_messageView != null) {
        _messageView.setText(code);
    }

    showDialog(null);
}
```

The Dialog displays, however _messageView is always null so I cannot have my message reflect my actions!

So my question is, how is it that I assigned it earlier yet it is null when I need it?